# How to create many lists on Android?

Tags: android, list, view

I am trying to create a to-do list application on Android.  I am stuck because at the moment I don't know the way to create many to-do lists.

I have created the GUI for one list, using ListView.  Entries of the list are added by the user when running the application.

In particular, I don't know how to pass a list object if i create new one.

Comment: Check out the Notepad sample app on the Android Developers' app. It's a similar concept. Multiple notes (todo lists), each of which are shown in a list, then can be displayed individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be set new data set adapter with `setAdapter()` method, but depending on Your app requirements changing updating dataset could be better option ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).

If You need have all list and only change them diuring runtime it could be good idea to have multiple listview and change only their visibility (I suggest using tabs http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

Comment: oh thank you very much for the tips!!! very appreciated! i will try to use both first and pick the one which is better fitting!!

thank you very much (bowing)